# I am trying to upgrade my spring boot application from 1.5.4 to 2.01 but i am getting "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger" error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, log4j

With 1.5.4 version logging was working fine.
List of libraries, i have upgraded ..
Spring Boot    : 1.5.4 to 2.0.1
Spring Framework :4.3.12 to 5.0.5
Jackson         : 2.9.0 to 2.9.0

When i added below dependencies it resolves the issue..

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.4</version>
</dependency>
```

But i think this is not the right way, as Spring Boot provides support for logging mechanism. Any inputs will be appreciated.

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring.boot.version>2.0.1.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
    <jackson.xml.version>2.9.5</jackson.xml.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.xml.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.xml.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.xml.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.xml.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.xml.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>23.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.56</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty-common</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20180130</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Cleaned up formatting and grammatical error.

Comment: What other dependencies do you have? Can you post the whole pom.xml? Spring Boot includes logging, but by default it includes Logback, not Log4J.

Comment: @dunni , I have added pom dependencies, to remind you same configuration was working fine with old configuration. I don't know why its looking for Log4j now.

Comment: Spring Boot 2 doesn't support log4j anymore it does however support log4j2.

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me, too. I only had to add

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me, too. I only had to add the org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.6.4, that was already enough. Unfortunately, I got a bunch of warnings. Such as "SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings." at the beginning of logging, and "log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger X" and "log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly". I fear that I haven't completely understood how to configure Spring/Spring Boot for log4j based libraries. I scanned the Internet for any useful information but couldn't find any.